# How to get the base url Programatically in zend expressive?

Tags: php, environment-variables, base-url, mezzio

I am working on an API application that will be run in different domains: http://example.com/,  http://sub.example.com/, http://example-another.com/. Part of the API responses needs to send out its *base_url*. So I am trying to find a way to dynamically collect the *base_url* and add it to my response.

I have a factory to initiate the action handler as follows:

```
class TestHandlerFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container) : TestHandler
    {

        return new TestHandler();
    }
}
```

Then my *action handler* is as follows:

```
class TestHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        ...
    }
    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {

       ...
    }
}
```

I am new to Zend world and I found the https://github.com/zendframework/zend-http/blob/master/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php probably a potential solution of my problem. However, I do not how to get that PHP-Environment object (or any other object that help me grab the base url) in the factory or handler class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zend-http is not used in expressive, it's for zend-mvc. In expressive [PSR-7 HTTP message interfaces](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-7-http-message.md) are used and by default this is handled in [zend-diactoros](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros).

```
class TestHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {
        // Get request URI
        $uri = $request->getUri();
        // Reconstruct the part you need
        $baseUrl = sprintf('%s://%s', $uri->getScheme(), $uri->getAuthority());
    }
}
```

More info can be found here: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros/blob/master/src/Uri.php

EDIT: You cannot grab the request details in the factory itself. This can only be done in Middleware or Handlers (which are sort of a middleware).

Comment: thanks. that works. In fact, I tried more object-oriented approach that also helped `$request->getUri()->withUserInfo("")->withPath("")->withQuery("")->withFragment("")`